# Multiple bibliographies with bibtexall and LyX

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, subdividing

I want to know how to include this script
http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/bibtexall in LyX in order to generate multiple bibliographies for a Master document and its child documents, each one of them having its own BibTeX generated bibliography.

In the above mentioned file there is the sentence "Place this file somewhere in your PATH" I want to know what's meant by "PATH" here?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Windows, OS X, some Linux flavor?

Comment: I'm using Windows and specifically Windows 7

Comment: The path is a list of folders in which the system will look for program files. ([Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))) I'm afraid I don't actually know which is the best folder to use in such cases, but probably someone else does.

Comment: @ML_TN: Have you figured out the problem? I'm also looking for the solution. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 : I did find some way out with LyX
after the insertion of Bibtex generated bibliography 
I did the following 

in the Latex preamble I inserted this code 
   \usepackage{comment}
   \includecomment{comment}
and in the document I did this:
   %\bibliographystyle{plain} 
   %\bibliography{name of the .bib file} 
where the .bib file contains all references to all the chapters

Comment: @ML_TN: Thanks for your feedback. Could you explain where you put the bibtexall file and in what format? I'm also using Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: @ML_TN: It would be nice if you answer your own question in more detail.

Comment: With no more detail, this looks 'too localised'.